# Change UIButton IBOutlet programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have two viewControllers, the first one has a button and when pressed another viewcontroller is presented containing a tableview. The tableView cell that is selected should be the new title to the button on the first viewController.

first viewController .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1Out;
- (IBAction)btn1:(id)sender;
```

first viewController .m

```
- (IBAction)btn1:(id)sender
{
viewcontroller2 = [[PopUpViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller2];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

viewController 2 .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentStartStation;
```

viewController 2 .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.selectedCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row+1];

[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


NewViewController *firstViewControllerObj = [[NewViewController alloc] init];

[firstViewControllerObj.btn1Out setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.selectedCell] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

When the viewController2 is dismissed the buttons title isn't changed. What's wrong?

Comment: you need to set a delegate for do that

Answer (score 0):

at first your title does not match the real question... second, no need to initialize new object of your first view controller, because it's still in the memory, you need to get access from second controller to first or try to use delegation to receive a new title from second view controller.